You don't have any iOS available to run this build, please make sure your environment is configured correctly and try again
I've been fighting with Expo for so long.
I'm trying to install an iOS build generated with EAS, but I keep getting the same error, even though I have the iOS simulator open and several iOS emulators running.



I've previously solved that issue, but I don't have a reproducible method. I've updated to Expo Orbit 1.2.0 (28).
Do you have any ideas?

Sigh
You have to target the iOS simulator.
I mistakenly sent a build to a physical iOS device.
Wrong:
eas build --profile development --platform ios

Correct:
eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios

In which these profiles are described by eas.json:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">=1.0.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_ENV": "DEVELOPMENT"
      }
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "extends": "development",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    }
  }
}

Note the ios.simulator path. It needs to be set to true.
